# Как вставить в запрос переменную

Tags: c#, база-данных

Хочу передать в запросе переменную. Имею код:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string m = textBox1.Text;
      DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
      OleDbDataAdapter da4 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Ссылка, Дата FROM Данные WHERE Месяц=8;", oleDbConn);
      da4.Fill(ds4, "St");
      dataGridView1.DataSource = ds4.Tables[0];
}
```

Подскажите, как заменить код так, чтобы вместо цифры 8 была переменная m, которую пользователь вводит с формы:

```
string m = textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Предвосхищая другой вопрос - куда прикручивать эти самые параметры: [OleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, в OleDB провайдер можно передавать параметр, но это требует немного [другого синтаксиса](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx), в котором не используется @-нотация для параметра:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string m = textBox1.Text;
    DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da4 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Ссылка, Дата FROM Данные WHERE Месяц=?", oleDbConn);
    da4.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
        "@month", OleDbType.VarWChar, 80).Value = m;
    da4.Fill(ds4, "St");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds4.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: `@CategoryName`, `.VarChar` ? Скопировано из примера https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: @Igor Да, более того не нужно было дублировать ссылку из моего ответа. Спасибо за внимательность в типе данных. А вот имя переменной, кажется, будет проигнорировано, не так ли?

Comment: У автора поле `Месяц` - определенно число.

Comment: Параметром должна быть строка взятая из текст бокса. Если нужно число, можно прикрутить парсер, но это не относится к сути вопроса.

Comment: Тип параметра - `OleDbType` - вряд ли будет `NVarChar`. Явно должен быть один из числовых типов.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш вариант рабочий, это ответ. Но не могли бы вы подсказать, что означает цифра 80 в строке SelectCommand.Parameters.Add?

Comment: @Алексей - 80 - это длина параметра типа `*Var*Char`. Автору ответа несколько раз советовали поправить тип параметра на числовой, ни в какую... Поставьте такой `OleDbType`, какой у вас в таблице для поля `Месяц`.

Answer (score -2):

Если версия C# 6+:

```
OleDbDataAdapter da4 = new OleDbDataAdapter($"SELECT Ссылка, Дата FROM Данные WHERE Месяц={m};", oleDbConn);
```

Если нет:

```
 OleDbDataAdapter da4 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Ссылка, Дата FROM Данные WHERE Месяц=" + m + ";", oleDbConn);
```

Comment: "Уж сколько раз твердили миру, ..." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @Igor всё равно надо в начале убедиться ,что пользователь ввел допустимое значение; лучше вообще использовать что-то типа NumericUpDown.