# Как передать запрос к бд с формы?

Tags: c#, база-данных

Подскажите, как правильно сделать запрос к БД с формы. Как я понимаю, делать это надо с помощью инъекций:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string f = textBox3.Text;
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("?;", oleDbConn);
    da1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
        "@month", OleDbType.Variant).Value = f;
    da1.Fill(ds1, "St");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
}
```

Что не приводит к результату.

Ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException" в System.Data.dll
>   Дополнительные сведения: Ошибочная инструкция SQL; предполагалось 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT' или 'UPDATE'.

Предполагается делать к базе простенькие запросы по типу `SELECT Столбец 1, Столбец 2 FROM Таблица WHERE Что-то`

Comment: "Что не приводит к результату." - а к чему приводит?

Comment: [Дубликат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748713/184217)

Comment: Приводит к ошибке: Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException" в System.Data.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Ошибочная инструкция SQL; предполагалось 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT' или 'UPDATE'.

Comment: Извиняюсь, в предыдущем вопросе вставлялась переменная, но как я понял целый запрос таким способом передать нельзя. Поправьте если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Информацию об ошибке следует добавить в вопрос. Строка `"?;"` не является правильным SQL запросом.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by7t044k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Вы зачем добавили в вопрос фразу из моего комментария?

Comment: Ваша фраза по сути описывает ошибку, извините, сейчас заменю на оригинал.

Comment: _как я понял целый запрос таким способом передать нельзя_ - всё верно. Через параметры можно передавать только значения.